# Can IOTA Smart Contracts access IOTA Streams channels or vice versa?

Tags: smart-contract, streams

I am currently learning how IOTA Smart Contract Protocol works. From what I have been able to read, the ISCP is a second layer protocol which off-Tangle executes smart contracts. However, its state is updated in the Tangle as a hash based on a commitee computation result. Also, I read that you can interact with a smart contract by sending it a transaction and here is where my doubt comes out.

It is possible to interact with a smart contract from a IOTA Streams channel? Or vice versa, can IOTA smart contracts access IOTA Streams channels?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Smart Contracts can't store any secrets.
You'd need a middleware to access the streams from Smart Contracts trigger.